# Почему except KeyboardInterrupt выполняется раньше, чем myParser.print_help()?

Tags: python, парсер, исключения, print

Ниже отрывок из моего кода. Программе не всегда предоставляется файл на `stdin`, и после <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> она не должна выплевывать никаких трейсов, просто чистенько выходить, выдавать в консоль `print` и сообщение `help` из парсера.

```
try:
    fileInpath = sys.stdin.read()#возвращает строку
    if not(fileInpath):
        print('\nОтсутствует входящий файл')
        myParser.print_help()
        sys.exit()  
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Программа сейчас делает только print и выходит без ошибок, если в консоль ввожу

```
prog.py -i
```

То есть `fileInpath` равен `None`, `stdin` ничего не получил.
НО! Когда печатаю в консоли:

```
type E | prog.py
```

У меня появляется и `print`, и `help` из парсера.

Вопрос: почему e`xcept KeyboardInterrupt` выполняется раньше, чем `myParser.print_help()`? И как сделать так, чтобы help выводился в первом случае, как и во втором?

Comment: Я что-то не понял, с чего вы сделали вывод, что KeyboardInterrupt выполняются раньше. Вообще, у меня `./prog.py` и `./prog.py -i` выполняются абсолютно одинаково, ожидая строку на входе и выполняя `print_help` при её отсутствии, и я не вижу никаких причин, чтобы поведение было каким-то другим. Может, уточните операционную систему и *полный и точный* (копировать-вставить) ввод-вывод в консоли?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы нажимаете <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, то в python по умолчанию выбрасывает `KeyboardInterrupt` исключение.

Когда ввод предоставляется через `type E |`, то `sys.stdin.read()` читает весь ввод и возвращается: вы вероятно не успеваете нажать <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, поэтому и `print()` и `myParser.print_help()` выполняются.

Если же вы нажимаете <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> пока код висит на `sys.stdin.read()`, то код прыгает в `except KeyboardInterrupt` блок: все промежуточные строки НЕ выполняются, то есть `print()` и `myParser.print_help()` не выполняются вообще (не раньше, не позже).